# regex match some special chars

Tags: php, regex, special-characters

I have a strings like this:

```
  hello this is my_string is-very-cool & another stuff
```

How I can explode(?) my string by all special chars but allowing the spaces, - and _ ?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_split('/[^\w -]/', $string)
```

This will split on anything that isn't a-z, 0-9, _, - or a space.

Comment: was too easy!, need to go deep on regex! thank you.